# How to compare Node object and FXMLLoader.load return value which may be of type Node

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I have a next() method to load the next FXML file at the center of the Borderpane bp.

```
@FXML
    private void next(ActionEvent event) {
        Parent currentPage= bp.getCenter().getParent();
        System.err.println(getPageNo(currentPage));
        
        if(getPageNo(currentPage)==1){
            loadPage2();
        }else if(getPageNo(currentPage)==2){
            loadPage3();
        }else if(getPageNo(currentPage)==3){
            loadPage4();
        }
    }
```

and I made a method getPageNo() to get the existing page at the center of bp

```
int getPageNo(Node currentNode) {
        try{
            Node node1=FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/View_FXMLGUI/AddStudent1FXML.fxml"));
            Node node2=FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/View_FXMLGUI/AddStudent2FXML.fxml"));
            Node node3=FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/View_FXMLGUI/AddStudent3FXML.fxml"));
            Node  node4=FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/View_FXMLGUI/AddStudent4FXML.fxml"));
```

// for verifying the output

```
            System.err.println("value is  "+node1.equals(currentNode));
            
            if(node1.equals(currentNode)){
                return 1;
            }else if(node2.equals(currentNode)){
                return 2;
            }else if(node3.equals(currentNode)){
                return 3;
            }else if(node4.equals(currentNode)){
                return 4;
            }
        
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Error in getting page no method");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

I need to load the fxml file at the center of the borderpane bp according to existing loaded fxml at the center of boarderPane bp. Please help me....

Comment: Why would the nodes be equal?  You should provide a [mcve].  You probably want `==` not `equals()`, but that is not your primary issue.

Comment: *"Now I want to compare both to verify that whether the node is present in center of the BorderPane bp is same fxml node."* It can't be the same node. The `FXMLLoader` will create new nodes whenever `load()` is called.

Comment: please read the referenced help page and act accordingly - and make sure you understand the comment by @James_D: your currentNode will __never__ be the same instance as __any__ of the pages, as long as you re-load all every time you test for a match! A possible solution to your requirement might be to load them once and keeping references to all (f.i. in a List). Though I suspect a xy-problem, so best to describe what you want to achieve _exactly_ along with providing a minimal, reproducible example :)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing any of this in the first place? Why not use the simple and obvious solution:

```
private int currentPage = 0 ;

@FXML
private void next() throws IOException {
    currentPage++;
    URL url = getClass().getResource("/View_FXMLGUI/AddStudent"+currentPage+"FXML.fxml")
    Node view = FXMLLoader.load(url);
    bp.setCenter(view);
}
```